# How progressive is Catarrhal Stomatitis?

Tags: cats, diseases, dental-care

My friend plans to adopt a stray kitten. The kitten is 6 months old, very well behaving and apparently he has catarrhal stomatitis.

Apparently, as [this post](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28855/what-are-the-main-alternatives-to-tooth-extraction-for-feline-stomatitis) suggests, the best way to deal with this disease is to extract the teeth.

This cat has one tooth that has been affected very badly, so the vet believes there is no way to save it. Currently, he is on antibiotics to determine if the disease is autoimmune or viral and if it is autoimmune they say that the disease will spread to other teeth and removing them all at once might be the best way to proceed. However, in case it is viral, they will only extract the effected tooth.

If the disease is indeed autoimmune, is it certain that the rest of the disease will spread to the other teeth? It makes sense to remove all the teeth while he is under anaesthesia, but if there is a good chance he might retain the rest of the teeth, for the quality of life purposes, removing only the effected tooth might be better.

Thanks